# find() and findIndex() in lib.es6.d.ts

Tags: typescript

Is there a reason why Array.prototype.findIndex() definition doesn't include index and object whereas Array.prototype.find() does?

```
find(predicate: (value: T, index: number, obj: Array<T>) => boolean, thisArg?: any): T;

findIndex(predicate: (value: T) => boolean, thisArg?: any): number;
```

I keep getting this error:

> Argument of type '(v: number, i: any, a: any) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: number) => boolean'.
>   (parameter) v: number

when I'm using it like this:

```
arr.findIndex( (v, i, a) => {/*..*/} )
```

Am I supposed to edit the .d.ts file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a "bug" in the standard definition.
According to the spec, it takes the standard Array predicate function:  https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.findindex

I would create a bug report on typescript's github and locally overload `findIndex` with the right signature.

Comment: Maybe add code which shows how to "locally overload the `findIndex` method"?